# FreeImage.dll compiled for Windows CE?

Tags: c++, arm, windows-ce, freeimage, jpeg2000

I need to process data for a jpeg200 to display on a CE5/ARM4VI device, so I'm attempting to compile FreeImage.dll using VS2008 and the CE5 SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17310)

I'm not having much luck getting FreeImage's static libraries compiled.  So far types.h, io.h and sstream, which seem to be necessary to compile the libs, aren't available in the CE5 SDK includes.

Before I go into more details about the compile errors, can anyone answer whether if compiling FreeImage.dll is even possible for CE5, specifically the ARM4VI platform?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible (except saying the letter B with a closed mouth).

You will probably have to create your custom classes for each which is in the standart library and is used by FreeImage but is not in the SDK. for all other code it's probably just simple parameter/types updates :)

Maybe you can get [STLport](http://www.stlport.com/) working on CE.